# Как для символа C вывести два символа, первый из которых опережает символ C в кодовой таблице , а второй следует за символом C

Tags: c

Решение данного вопроса должно быть в функцие task 2

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<locale.h>


void task1();
void task2();
void task3();
void task4();
void task5();
void task6();

char C,V,K;
int N;
void main(){
     task1();
  task2();
 task3();
 task4();
 task5();
}

void task1(){
   /*do {

   N=getch();
  printf ("\nN: ");
   putchar(N);


  } while (32<=N<=126);
  getch();*/
  printf("task1:");
  scanf("%d",&N);
            if(N<32||N>126)printf("error");
            else printf("\nSymbol:%c,kod:%d",N,N);
putchar(N);
  }

void task2(){
   printf("\ntask2:");
   C=getche();
   K=C-1;
   V=C+1;
printf("smaller: %c.", K);
printf("bigger: %c.", V);

   /*scanf("%c",&C);
   do {
V=C+1;
   C=getchar();

   printf ("You enter %c. ASCII code = %d\n", V, (int)V);
     } while (C<V);
     do {
K=C-1;
   C=getchar();

   printf ("You enter %c. ASCII code = %d\n", K, (int)K);
     } while (K>V);*/

}

void task3(){
char M[100];
        for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
            printf("firs elements:%d",M[i]);
            printf("%c",'A'+i);
        }
}
void task4(){
    char Z[100];
        for(int i=0;i<26;i--){
            printf("last elements:%d",Z[i]);
            printf("%c",'z'+i);
}
}
//void task5(char* str){
void task5(char* str){
{
    int alpha = 0;
    int digits = 0;

    while(*str !=0)
    {
        alpha++;
        if(isdigit(*str++))
            digits++;
    }
    if(C=digits)printf("\ndigits");
       else printf("alpha");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что не работает-то?

Только я б на вашем месте, если уж так хотите работать - хотя бы разделял вывод в разные строки:

```
void task2()
{
    printf("\ntask2:");
    C=getche();
    K=C-1;
    V=C+1;
    printf("\n\nsmaller: %c.\n", K);
    printf("bigger: %c.\n", V);
}
```

Получается что-то вроде

```
task2:j

smaller: i.
bigger: k.
```

Что не так?

Comment: у меня идёт почему-то вечный error

Comment: А он уже не связан с `task2`. Вы читали, как правильно задавать вопросы? В "справке"? В курсе, что *вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.*? Вы так уверенно ткнули в task2, что, простите, никто и не думал смотреть что-то еще :)

Comment: Вы, наверное, просто не успеваете и увидеть, что там выводится - потому что в task3 просто выбрасываете непонятно какой мусор из не инициализированного массива `M` одной макарониной, не заборять о переходах на новую строку, например... Как и в task 4. При этом написав почти бесконечный цикл `for(int i=0;i<26;i--)` - ну-ка, прикиньте, сколько раз он выполнится, пока **уменбшающееся от 0** число не превысит 26?

Comment: Ну так как, может, удалите этот вопрос и зададите новый - нормально? Да и код заодно хоть немного отформатируете, чтоб он не выглядел таким инвалидом...

Comment: Спасибо большое)))